# dlib : Unable to open face_landmark_detection_ex for reading?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dlib

I compiled [dlib](http://dlib.net/) library and face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp example program in visual studio as described in [Demo for compiling dlib in visual studio][2] and it was build successfully and executable is created. But when I try to execute the executable on terminal as:

```
C:\mydir>dlibProject.exe face_landmark_detection_ex shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat faces/*.jpg
```

It showes an error:

```
exception thrown!
Unable to open ./face_landmark_detection_ex for reading.
```

if anyone have any knowledge and experience on dlib please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just do `C:\mydir>dlibProject.exe shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat faces/*.jpg`, as `face_landmark_detection_ex` is the name of the program that you apparently changed.

Comment: I have tried that and gives `exception thrown! unable to open faces/*.jpg` in that case it considered faces/*.jpg as a file.

Comment: You also need to specify a **single** jpg image in the folder. e.g. C:\mydir>dlibProject.exe shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat faces/sample.jpg